# Spark on K8s: executor node pending forever

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

```
cpchung:small$ kubectl get pods
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
simpleapp-1581273108724-driver   1/1     Running   0          93m
simpleapp-1581273108724-exec-1   0/1     Pending   0          93m
```

My kubectl version:

```
cpchung:spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.2", GitCommit:"59603c6e503c87169aea6106f57b9f242f64df89", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-21T22:17:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12", GitVersion:"v1.12.0", GitCommit:"0ed33881dc4355495f623c6f22e7dd0b7632b7c0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-09-27T16:55:41Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

from kubectl logs :

```
20/02/08 21:06:09 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ShuffleMapStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[7] at count at SimpleApp.java:12) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0))
20/02/08 21:06:09 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
20/02/08 21:06:24 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

After running `minikube start --kubernetes-version v1.12.0 --cpus 4 --memory 8192` with more cpus and memories , the pod description for the executor pod is showing this:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                 ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  83s (x541 over 91m)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient cpu, 1 Insufficient memory.
```

For the driver pod:

```
Events:          <none>
```

What could go wrong here?

Here is the repo which can reproduce the problem:
https://github.com/pokeai/k8s_setup/tree/master/small

Comment: Hi, could you please attach the result of executing `kubectl describe pod simpleapp-1581195917931-exec-1` ? The part the might be important is section `Events:` in the bottom.

Comment: Also you should remove `.master(local[*])` from SparkSession declaration in your app code: `SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("Simple Application").getOrCreate();`

Comment: fixed and attached the pod description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the description of your Pending pod: `0/1 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient cpu, 1 Insufficient memory.`, which means that you cluster has not enough resources to run the Pod.

To overcome it you have 2 options:

- Increase the resources amount of the Minikube cluster; you can do that by adding additional parameters to the cluster creation command: `minikube start ... --cpus 4 --memory 8192`
- Change CPU and memory requests for the Spark Pods; it's a bit trickier and to get the idea how Spark Driver and Executor resources requests are set please refer to [driver](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/features/BasicDriverFeatureStep.scala) and [executor](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/features/BasicExecutorFeatureStep.scala) spec setups.

Note that you cannot change Driver Pod CPU requests, its value is always set to 1 core. Also take into account that there is some memory [overhead](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/features/BasicDriverFeatureStep.scala#L54) added to the requested amount for both driver and executor Pods.

Hope it helps.

Comment: tried running with more cpus and memories. Now the pod descriptions are showing different erroes.

Comment: But now there are only warns which is fine, your Pods should be running. Please check it with ‘kubectl get pods’.

Comment: still pending forever:

cpchung:small$ kubectl get pods
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
simpleapp-1581273108724-driver   1/1     Running   0          57m
simpleapp-1581273108724-exec-1   0/1     Pending   0          57m

Comment: But your description says that the container has started. Are you sure you attached Spark Executor Pod’s (which is pending) ‘kubectl describe pod ...’ output?

Comment: I've checked your repo and I succeeded to run the Job. Several more things you can check: `kubectl describe nodes` (check CPU and Memory capacity of the node), `kubectl describe pod <driver>` and `kubectl describe pod <executor>` (check `Requests` CPU and Memory values).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207508/discussion-between-cpchung-and-aliaksandr-sasnouskikh).